# jquery ajax - add a common param to each ajax request

Tags: jquery

I want to add a param on each ajax request globally. So tried with `ajaxSend`. But there is no `data` object in settings (3rd parameter). Is there a way to add a common param on each request. Request may be in any type (GET, POST, etc...).

I tried like this.

```
$( document ).ajaxSend(function(event, jqxhr, settings) {
   //i have to manipulate data object here. So i can add an additional param. 
   //OR i need equivalent to this.
});
```

Comment: Share your javascript code so we can see what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/)

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
// Modify options, control originalOptions, store jqXHR, etc
});
```

It will allow you to process the request and update any option before the request is issued

Answer (score 0):

I added extra param like below.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
     options.url = options.url + "?appId=" + appId;
});
```

But changing `originalOptions` data object not taking any effect. So i'm not sure what i did above work in all case. But for me, it works in all types (GET, POST etc).